# Why is'NaN' in JavaScript and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript

I have created a program that tells you a program that takes a number in JavaScript and tells you the various properties of that number.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            
            var div_sum = 0
            var num = Number(prompt('Please enter the number'))
            var pn_result = true
            for(var i = 2; i < num; i++){
                if(num % i === 0){
                    var pn_result = false
                    break
                }
            }
            if(pn_result){
                alert(String(num) + 'is a prime')
            } else {
                alert(String(num) + 'is not a prime\n' + String(num) + '=' + String(i) + 'x' + String(num / i))
            }
            var div_list = []
            for(var div = 1; div < num + 1; div++){
                if(num % div === 0){
                    div_list.push(div)
                }
            }
            var div_len = div_list.length
            alert('Number of divisor is' + String(div_len) )
            
            for(var i = 0; i < div_len + 1; i++){
                var div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
            }
            var div_sum = div_sum - num
            alert(div_sum)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the end, I was curious if that number was a perfect number, so I output the sum of the divisor excluding myself.

But the execution result came out as'NaN'.

Oddly enough, the other operations did so in a finished state.
What is'NaN' and how do I fix it?

Comment: NaN means "not a number" - so `Number('abcde')` results in `NaN` - by the way, `typeof NaN === 'number'` so, *Not A Number* is a number :p - as for "how do I fix it" ... it's not broken, it is a Number that isn't a Number (so NaN has toFixed and toPrecision and toExponential methods just like any other Number)

Comment: I would recommend as a FIRST test after `var num = Number(prompt('Please enter the number'))` checking if `isNaN(num)` or `Number.isNaN(num)` to avoid further complications in your code (note, don't check if `num === NaN` since `NaN !== NaN`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is this line. You are iterating 1 more time than the length of `div_list`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < div_len + 1; i++){
  var div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
}
```

It should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < div_len; i++){
  var div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
}
```

Other issues include declaring redeclaring `div_sum` inside the `for loop`, and again immediately outside. You should declare it only once, and then reassign new values to it as such.

```
var div_sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < div_len + 1; i++){
  div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
}
div_sum = div_sum - num;
```

And finally, you should also use `camelCase` to name `JavaScript` variables. That is the normal convention. Instead, you are using the `snake_case` convention, which is not usually used in `JavaScript` land.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
for(var i = 0; i < div_len + 1; i++)
  {
    var div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
  }
```

to this and it will work

```
for(var i = 0; i < div_len; i++)
   {
     var div_sum = div_sum + div_list[i]
   }
```